# How can we check if string is a version number or not

Tags: shell, unix

How to check if a string contains version in numberic/decimal format in shell script

for eg we have 1.2.3.5 or 2.3.5

What if we do not have a constraint on the number of characters we have in here. It could x.x.x.x or x.x as well.

Comment: A regular expression?

Comment: Do you care about -alpha versions, RC versions, -stable versions, etc?

Comment: Hope that your script doesn't contain IP addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [*bash regular expressions*](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/advanced_bash_scripting_guide/x13357.html):

```
echo -n "Test: "
read i

if [[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){2,3}$ ]]; 
then
  echo Yes
fi
```

This accepts `digits.digits.digits` or `digits.digits.digits.digits`

Change `{2,3}` to shrink or enlarge the acceptable number of `.digits` (or  `{2,}` for "at least 2")

- `^` means beginning of string
- `[0-9]+` means at least one digit
- `\.` is a dot
- `(...){2,3}` accepts 2 or 3 of what's inside the `()`
- `$` means end of string

Comment: You could use `{2,}` to remove the upper bound: 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks. Re the question, it seems to be 3 or 4 numbers, but, indeed, that could be *at least 2* (+1, the first)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using `bash`, you can use the `=~` regex match binary operator, for example:

```
pax> if [[ 1.x20.3 =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]] ; then echo yes ; fi

pax> if [[ 1.20.3 =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]] ; then echo yes ; fi
yes
```

For your particular test data, the following regex will do the trick:

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*$
```

(a number followed by any quantity of `.<number>` extensions) although, if you want to handle edge cases like `1.2-rc7` or `4.5-special`, you'll need something a little more complex.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're truly restricted to the Bourne shell, then use *expr*:

```
if expr 1.2.3.4.5 : '^[0-9][.0-9]*[0-9]$' > /dev/null; then
  echo "yep, it's a version number"
fi
```

I'm sure there are solutions involving awk or sed, but this will do.

Comment: Actually, this would accept "1..2", which might not be acceptable to you.

Answer (score -2):

Flip the logic: check if it contains an "invalid" character:

```
$ str=1.2.3.4.5; [[ $str == *[^0-9.]* ]] && echo nope || echo yup
yup
$ str=123x4.5;   [[ $str == *[^0-9.]* ]] && echo nope || echo yup
nope
```

Downside to this answer:

```
$ str=123....; [[ $str == *[^0-9.]* ]] && echo nope || echo yup
yup
```