# Check if a string contains a Version with more than 3 decimal points

Tags: c#, if-statement, decimal, version

I am trying to get a the sub releases of a program, and this returns the following string `Release 4.2.3 of programX` but also sometimes: `Release 4.3 of programX`.
I want to do a check if the string contains 3 or more decimal places (like 4.3.2).
I found [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056374/how-can-we-check-if-string-is-a-version-number-or-not)  with answer but it's not for C#, is this possible in C# and if so what would be the best approach?

Comment: C# can work with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841883/regular-expressions-c-sharp-is-it-possible-to-extract-matches-while-matching

Comment: If text only contains the version number as string It could be interesting to use Version.Parse or TryParse but if there is text around that would need too substring first and in that case a regex if probably better

Comment: @Djeroen you are wanting to check if string contains 3 or more decimals but your example only depicts 2

Comment: @MethodMan that is because im running this in a for loop, and sometimes it has two decimals an ohter times it has 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use linq.

```
bool more3dec = input.Count(c => c == '.') >= 2;
```

Or regex. (Checking only points within numeric part)

```
bool more3dec = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+");
```

Comment: just cross finger the real "programX" text doesn't have any dot inside :)

Comment: Yeah. Added regex for that. @Sehnsucht

Comment: Your regex returns true: "Release 11111 1.1.1" :)

Comment: @Chase that was for check not validation ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i used the linq method because my string never contains a dot outside the versionnumber, and the regex gave me this error: `unrecognized escape sequance`

Comment: Glad it helped! Sorry for the error you got. I forgot to put `@` sign before string so it becomes verbatim string. @Djeroen

Answer (score 1):

you can do this quite a view ways but if you want to know if it have `2 periods .`
or not then you can do this for instance.

```
var versionStr = "Release 4.2.3";
var nuberDecimals = versionStr.Split('.').Length - 1;
```

> nuberDecimals = 2;

Comment: he said that he want's to know if it's > 3 perhaps the OP is missing a `.`

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "Release 4.2.3 andSomeText.With.Dots.Or.Namespaces";
var isValid = Regex.IsMatch(input.Split(' ')[1], @"\d+\.\d+\.\d+");
```

Comment: here you can easily get a null reference exception